# Is there an output equivalent to getline(cin, x) on C++?

Tags: c++

I like how getline(cin, x) works for reading stuff. Unlike cin >> x, it doesn't mess up the buffer and it seems to allow European characters like á, é, etc too.
I was just wondering if there's an output equivalent to this, because cout << x doesn't allow European characters and maybe there's a better option than that.

Comment: Wait, what platform, C++ compiler and library?  That should not be the case.

Comment: What platform (OS, compiler, libc version, terminal app)?  Handling of non-ASCII characters is very platform-specific.

Comment: Windows Vista (ouch, not my computer) and VC++ 2010 Express, if that helps

Comment: If x is a std::string then cout << x should (does) work whatever the character set. The problem you may be encountering is that your terminal does not know how to display the characters. To help with this we need more information about the system you are using (Win/Mac/Linux) terminal type etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [std::wcout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sda3xxca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it is designed to support wide char strings and should work fine with european characters. It has the same usage as std::cout, but you will need the wide string literal prefix 'L':

```
std::wcout << L"My cool string.";
```

Comment: That `L` isn't a macro. It's built into the language.

Comment: Changed macro to unicode literal, since that's what it means.

Comment: Nitpick: It doesn't mean Unicode, it means wide character.  There are some other wide character encoding in use that Unicode.

Comment: Don;t get confused with encoding support. The language (currently) is encoding agnostic. How the terminal interprets  the encoding is another thing completely.

Comment: So I changed it to "wide string literal prefix". That doesn't exactly impress myself for being concise, so if you know any better name, feel free to override my changes.

Answer (score 1):

See [Michael Kaplan’s blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/) for Unicode issues in Windows. For the console, especially the following posts are relevant:

- [Myth busting in the console](http://www.siao2.com/2010/10/07/10072032.aspx)
- [Conventional wisdom is retarded](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx)